# ios set UIDatePicker time ahead

Tags: ios, nsdate, uidatepicker, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I grab the current time

```
NSDate * now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents * comps = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
```

And I can set the DatePicker to any values I desire

```
NSDate * date = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
[self.off setDate:date animated:TRUE];
```

But how do I add a, say, 5 minutes to "now"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5*60];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:300 sinceDate:[NSDate date]]
```